# How to read text from file edit it and print using in ASSEMBLY

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I am trying to create a assembly 8086 program which scans input.txt file and searches for string "word". The result should be output.txt with the same text from input.txt but strings "word" should be replaced with "new_word".

Program compiles and starts but output.txt is not created.
I think the problem is with CMP instruction and values used with it. What would be correct way to perform comparison?

Any help would be really appreciated because there isn't much info on the internet about TURBO (TASM) Assembler.

```
.data
    file_name db "input.txt", 0
    output_name db "output.txt", 0
    new_word db "new_word", 13, 10, "$"
    file_hand dw 0
    output_file_hand dw 0
    counter db 0
    buffer db 1 dup(0), "$"
    buffer2 db 10 dup(0), "$"
```

COMPARISON FUNCTION:

```
checking:
    mov al, ds:[buffer]
    cmp al, 77h ; comparing to letter 'w'
    je reading_word
    jmp printing_symbol
    jmp reading
```

FUNCTION checks if 3 continuing bytes make "word"

```
reading_word: ;
    mov bx, file_hand
    mov ah, 3fh
    mov al, 0
    mov cx, 3
    mov dx, offset buffer2
    mov file_hand, bx ; updating file_hand
    mov al, ds:[buffer2 + 1]
    cmp al, 6fh ; comparing to letter 'o'
    inc counter
    mov al, ds:[buffer2 + 2]
    cmp al, 72h ; comparing to letter 'r'
    inc counter
    mov al, ds:[buffer2 + 3]
    cmp al, 64h ; comparing to letter 'd'
    inc counter
    ;if "word" found
    cmp counter, 3
    je printing_string
    jmp reading
```

FULL APPLICATION CODE: https://pastecode.io/s/esostirn

I have tried different ways to CMP value in the buffer but could not make it work.

Comment: What error, on what line?  An [mcve] needs to quote the actual error message if there is one.  It might not mean anything to you, but that's why you're asking other people.  Also, EMU8086 is a different assembler than TASM.  Untag [emu8086] if you're not actually using that editor/assembler/simulator.

Comment: @peterCordes Thank you for advice, specified the question and cut out unneeded code.

Comment: Nothing uses the FLAGS results of those `cmp` instructions, so you're just unconditionally incrementing a memory location (which you didn't reset to zero before that block of code). Have you single-stepped this with a debugger?  If not, do so.  There are other bugs like `jmp reading` is unreachable after `jmp printing_symbol`.

Comment: To check for a 4-byte match (like memcmp with a constant) starting at a pointer in BX, you'd normally do something like `cmp word ptr [bx], 6f77h` / `jne nomatch`  / `cmp word ptr [bx+2], 6472h` / `jne nomatch` else fall through to "word" found.  Where `nomatch` is wherever execution should go in that case.  Checking for a single byte as a candidate for the start of the match is sensible, especially if you're scanning through a buffer to look for it at any starting offset.

Comment: Try printing it to the screen first and then see if it works with a file. That way you can narrow down where your logic error is happening.